# Somar valores de um array com PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário onde ele é construído conforme a quantidade de usuários. Vejam:

```
        <?php
        ....
        while($pe = mysqli_fetch_object($sql))
        {
            ....
        $visualizar .= '<div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="LancarNotas1[]" class="form-control" value="'.$ctcb->serie1.'"></div>';
        $visualizar .= '<div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="LancarNotas2[]" class="form-control" value="'.$ctcb->serie2.'"></div>';
        $visualizar .= '<div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="LancarNotas3[]" class="form-control" value="'.$ctcb->serie3.'"></div>';
        $visualizar .= '<div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="LancarNotas4[]" class="form-control" value="'.$ctcb->serie4.'"></div>';
        $visualizar .= '<div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" name="LancarNotas5[]" class="form-control" value="'.$ctcb->serie5.'"></div>';
        ....
        }
    $visualizar .= '<div class="form-group" align="center">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnBuscar">Lançar Resultados</button>
                    </div>';
return $visualizar;
```

Quando é lançado os valores, recupero da seguinte forma:

```
public function cadastrarNotas($usuarios,$notas1,$notas2,$notas3,$notas4,$notas5)
  {
      for($a = 0; $a < count($usuarios); $a++)
      {
         mysqli_query($this->conexao,"UPDATE provas SET serie1 = '".$notas1[$a]."',serie2 = '".$notas2[$a]."',serie3 = '".$notas3[$a]."',serie4 = '".$notas4[$a]."',serie5 = '".$notas5[$a]."' WHERE usuarios = '".$usuarios[$a]."';");

      }
     if(mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexao) > 0)
    {
          $_SESSION["SucessoNotas"] = time() + 5;         
          return "<script>window.location.href='".$this->caminhoAbsoluto()."/cadastrar-resultados/';</script>";
    }
  }
```

Só que preciso limitar os valores das notas em até 200, ou seja, que as notas somadas de todos os usuários não ultrapassem 200.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você teria que esperar o usuário digitar os valores, e antes do update por exemplo, verificar se a soma de todas aquelas notas ultrapassou 200, caso sim, retornar um erro. Melhor que isso, seria através de JavaScript, você poderia capturar o submit do botão talvez, e verificar se ultrapassou 200, e alertar o erro através do próprio JS, evitando atualizar a página e perder as informações digitadas. Seria isso sua dúvida?

Comment: Na verdade é o que preciso, somar os valores, pois estou pegando os valores depois do usuário digitar. Porém acredito que isso dê para fazer com PHP.

Comment: Você poderia deixar todas as tag "name" iguais, pois quando você faz a captura via "POST" ou "GET", irá vir em forma de array, se caso vier, basta fazer um foreach com uma váriavel somando foreach($_POST['LancarNotas'] as $notas){ variavel = variavel + $notas; } Será que isso resolveria seu problema, visto que você poderá ter vários inputs e terá o controle dos mesmos?

Answer (score -1):

Se entendi sua pergunta, você poderia salvar as notas em um array e utilizar o `array_reduce` para somar tudo.

```
$notas = [
    // ...
];

$soma = array_reduce($notas, function ($total, $nota) {
    /*
     * Verifica se o valor total é menor que 200 (limite).
     * Caso seja, incrementa com o valor da nota atual.
     */
    return $total += ($total < 200 ? $nota : 0);
}, 0);

echo $soma;
```

[PHP: array_reduce - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reduce.php)